# Keras LSTM: Bar plot of Feature Importance using SHAP

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, shap

I'm working on a LSTM for time series forecasting. Now I want to understand, which features impact the output the most and which ones aren't important. The goal is a bar plot like that using matplotlib in pycharm (reference: https://github.com/slundberg/shap):
[image]

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(num_neurons, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(SeqWeightedAttention())
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(1))
adam_opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=adam_lr, beta_1=adam_b1, beta_2=adam_b2, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=adam_opt, metrics=[metrics.mae, metrics.mape, metrics.mse])
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False, callbacks=[early_stop, checkpoint])

shap.initjs()
background = train_x[np.random.choice(train_x.shape[0], 100, replace=False)]
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, background)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(val_x)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, train_x, plot_type="bar", matplotlib=True)
plt.show()
```

And I get the following error calculating the shap_values (shap_values = ...):

```
ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 20 and 1. Shapes are [?,3,20] and [?,?,1]. for 'gradients/seq_weighted_attention_1/mul_grad/Select_1' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,?,1], [?,3,20], [?,3,20].
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's super hard to reproduce this error without the full code or the data. Could you post both to your question we we can help you?